# Mongo $in does not return results when used with "_id"

Tags: mongodb

I tried to run

`db.user.find({_id: { $in : ['561f9f6aae729de84253b8b7','561f9f72ae729de84253b8b9'] } } )`

it does not return any results even though results are there. Anything wrong with this query?

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("561f9f58ae729de84253b8b5"),
    "__v": NumberInt(0),
    "email": "Jay@admin.com",
    "gameStatus": "Left game",
    "isJudge": false,
    "isOnline": false,
    "login_at": ISODate("2015-10-15T12:43:04.346+0000"),
    "name": "Jay"
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("561f9f6aae729de84253b8b7"),
    "__v": NumberInt(0),
    "email": "sunil@admin.com",
    "gameStatus": "Just joined",
    "isJudge": false,
    "isOnline": true,
    "login_at": ISODate("2015-10-15T12:43:22.575+0000"),
    "name": "Sunil"
}
```

Comment: Solved! Had to use ObjectId() for _id column. Found from https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **ObjectId()**

```
db.user.find({_id: { $in : [ObjectId('561f9f6aae729de84253b8b7'),ObjectId('561f9f72ae729de84253b8b9')] } } )
```